# Multiple Threading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
Error:
        Exception in thread "Thread-2200" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
        at problem1.solvinging$solver.distancecalculator(Orienteering.java:107)
        at problem1.solveing$solver.run(Orienteering.java:165)
```

Class:

```
public void distancecalculator(char [][]problem  , int distancefound) {

    Point p = new Point();
    LinkedList<Point> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(origin);
    int []x = {1,-1,0,0};
    int []y = {0,0,1,-1};


    dist[0][0] = distancefound;
    while(!q.isEmpty()) {

        p = q.getFirst();
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            int a = p.x + x[i];
            int b = p.y + y[i];

            if(a >= 0 && b >= 0 && a < m && b < n && dist[a][b]==2) {

                dist[a][b] = 1 + dist[p.x][p.y] ;

                if(k>0) {
                    solver s = new solver(newproblem,dist[a][b]);
                    new Thread(s).start();
                }
```

I am getting the above error in my program while executing it
But the program is still running
How i correct it please help me
Thanks in advance.Suggest new edits if required

Comment: i am getting the above error in my console

Comment: You didn't tell **what** the error is. All you told is **where** it happens. A complete stack trace starts with something like "NullPointerException: foo may not be null" and then tells where the exception happens. We need to know what the exception type and message is.

Comment: OK. So read the error. It's extremely clear. You're creating too many threads, and the OS doesn't want to let you do that. Threads are a limited resource. You can't start as many threads as you want. Use an ExecutorService, which uses a pool of threads, or fix your algorithm if you think your code shouldn't start many threads.

Comment: @JBNizet would you please help  to edit my code so that i can use ExecutorService

Comment: No. That's your job.

Comment: Please supply more code - what is `k` what happens next in the loop?

Comment: @MichałSchielmann it 100x100 matrix an i am using BFS search in which one point can be visited by more than once , k is the number of Must visited points if k==0 i got the total distance it is working fine for 10x10 matrix

Comment: @user3970513 why not write it in the question. How should we know this? Does the program really work for 10x10 `problem` array and throws no error?

Comment: yes i think for large array size many threads are generated how to solve this is there any way that if threads generated>500 stop the first 100 threads

Comment: @MichałSchielmann is there any way if threads are generate more than 500 stop the first 100 threads

Comment: @user3970513 see my edited answer for a Semaphore example. It should be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you supplied there is no place where you remove elements from `LinkedList<Point> q`. 
The `getFirst()` method doesn't remove the first element. 
And probably because of that you've created an infinite loop, that creates new thread in every run.

Try `pollFirst()` instead.

**EDIT AFTER QUESTION EXPLANATION IN COMMENTS**

What you can do to limit the number of threads is using java.util.concurrent package i.e. [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).
Before you create new thread call `acquire` mehotd on the semapohre. Add the `semapohre` object to the `solver` construcotor, so that when the `solver` finishes it can call the `release()` mehtod in that solver object.

Try the code below to see how it would work:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new Main().run();
    }

    private void run() 
    {
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5, true);
        for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                semaphore.acquire(1);
                new TestThread(i, semaphore).start();
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e) {}

        }
    }

    class TestThread extends Thread
    {
        private Semaphore semaphore;
        private Integer id;

        TestThread(final Integer id, final Semaphore semaphore)
        {
            this.semaphore = semaphore;
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Thread " + id + " has started.");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread " + id + " has stopped.");
            semaphore.release(1);
        }
    }
}
```

There are 6 `threads` that need to be `run`, but the `semaphore` allows only 5 at a time. So the sixth has to wait. All `threads` do only one thing - wait for 5sec. So the sixth `thread` has to wait those 5sec so that one of the other threads can finish, and then it can start.

Output:

```
Thread 2 has started.
Thread 4 has started.
Thread 5 has started.
Thread 3 has started.
Thread 1 has started.
Thread 4 has stopped.
Thread 2 has stopped.
Thread 6 has started.  //here the sixth thread has started - as soon as the other ones finished.
Thread 1 has stopped.
Thread 3 has stopped.
Thread 5 has stopped.
```

Comment: my code check for the value of k if that value is find then stop the program

Comment: What is `k` exactly? It is not declared in the code you've provided. There is only check: `if(k>0)` then start new thread. If you won't remove the first element from the list, you'll get always the same element in every loop run (`p` would always be the same).

Comment: @user3970513 Knowing what you need(you could have explained it earlier in the question) I've edited my answer.

Comment: @user3970513 Edited - added some explanation tho the semaphore example.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have infite loop that causes OutOfMemoryError.
Check q can be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should be cautious when you are creating threads,especially about their number,because they are a **LIMITED** resource. Here you have a `while` loop and inside you have a `for` loop and inside that loop you are creating a `Thread`. You have no idea how many threads your java program is requesting from the underlying OS, then the OS denies,probably says "HOW ABOUT A NO?" to the JVM,and then JVM gives you that message as `OutOfMemoryError` . Try optimizing your code.